# series of toggling divs (n number of two divs that is toggled like checkbox) - JS

Tags: javascript, css, html, toggle

I have a table each one of them have a favorite option. I have used two star images to toggle between favorite and not favorite. ( I didnt use the checkbox because I want IE8 too).

I came up with the example below.

HTML

```
<div class="on" id="on_1" onclick="div_off(this.id);" style="display:none">off</div>
<div class="off" id="off_1" onclick="div_on(this.id);">on</div>
<div class="on" id="on_2" onclick="div_off(this.id);" style="display:none">off</div>
<div class="off" id="off_2" onclick="div_on(this.id);">on</div>
<div class="on" id="on_3" onclick="div_off(this.id);" style="display:none">off</div>
<div class="off" id="off_3" onclick="div_on(this.id);">on</div>
<div class="on" id="on_4" onclick="div_off(this.id);" style="display:none">off</div>
<div class="off" id="off_4" onclick="div_on(this.id);">on</div>
```

CSS

```
<style>
  .on, .off {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  .on{
    color: red;
  }
  .off{
    color: blue;
 }
</style>
```

JS:

```
<script>
        function div_on(onId){
            onId = onId.replace('off_','');
            var on = document.getElementById('on_'+onId);
            var off = document.getElementById('off_'+onId);
            on.style.display = "block"
            off.style.display = "none"

        }
        function div_off(offId){
            offId = offId.replace('on_','');
            var on = document.getElementById('on_'+offId);
            var off = document.getElementById('off_'+offId);
            on.style.display = "none"
            off.style.display = "block"
        }
    </script>
```

Is there an other simple way of doing the same. I am trying to avoid any js classes / jquery.

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/yellowandred/LZkVb/1/

Comment: do you just want to toggle text ?

Comment: I am using css sprites

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? I've also included an example on how to get the clicked element's ID.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="off" id="toggle1" onclick="toggle(this);">off</div>
<div class="off" id="toggle2" onclick="toggle(this);">off</div>
<div class="off" id="toggle3" onclick="toggle(this);">off</div>
<div class="off" id="toggle4" onclick="toggle(this);">off</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function toggle(el) {
    var newState = (el.className === "off") ? "on" : "off";

    el.className = newState;
    el.innerHTML = newState;
    alert("\"" + el.id + "\" is now " + newState + "!");
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.on, .off {
    cursor: pointer;
}
.on {
    color: red;
}
.off {
    color: blue;
}
```

[JSFiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/SombreErmine/LZkVb/6/)

[Browser support for these JavaScript properties.](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#all)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to use star images for on/off states I would create an image sprite (an image containing the two images of the star) and use it as background image in a div. Then you use CSS classes to control the position of the background image. For example:

HTML:

```
<div id="star1" class="star"></div>
<div id="star2" class="star"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.star {
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   background-image: url("img/starsprite.png");
   background-size: 20px 40px; /*We assume that the sprite contains a 20x20 px star in off state above a 20x20 px star in on state. Notice that the background is bigger than the div */
   background-position: 0px 0px;
   cursor: pointer;
}
.star.on {
   background-position: 0px 20px;
}
```

JS:

```
$('body').on('click', '#star', function(event) {
   var $this = $(this);
   if($this.hasClass('on')) {
      $this.removeClass('on');
   }
   else {
      $this.addClass('on');
   }
});
```

This way you halve the amount of DIVs needed. This is a quick example so you get the logic of the image sprite solution.
If you want to avoid jQuery it is possible with plain JavaScript as well, but I don't see the reason for not keeping things simple with jQuery.
There are a lot of tutorials on the web if you google for CSS image sprites.

This fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dJBKw/1/ uses on/off text like your example.